# Making asyncio tasks yield their control when blocked on IO

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

Consider the following example

```
import requests
import asyncio


async def main():
    for task_id in range(3):
        print(f"Scheduling task {task_id}")
        asyncio.create_task(dummy(task_id))


async def dummy(task_id):
    print(f"Executing task {task_id}")
    resp = requests.get(f"https://httpbin.org/ip").json()
    print(f"Completed task {task_id}")
    assert resp["origin"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is

```
Scheduling task 0
Scheduling task 1
Scheduling task 2
Executing task 0
Completed task 0
Executing task 1
Completed task 1
Executing task 2
Completed task 2
```

To my surprise, the tasks are executed in sequence, with noticeable latency in between, suggesting that the HTTP requests are not sent concurrently. How can I make each coroutine yield their control to each other when they block on some IO operation? That way I can have multiple HTTP requests on the fly, improving the throughput.

An obvious workaround is to switch to `aiohttp`, but I'm modeling a generic asynchronous IO operation. Using `aiohttp` may solve this particular problem, but it won't help when I'm talking to the filesystem, a PCIe bus, or an HDMI display, which presumably doesn't have an "async-aware" library.

Comment: You should definitely use aiohttp and native async libraries wherever possible. For the situations where you don't have an async-aware library, you can use `run_in_executor` which will use threads under the hood to "asincify" your sync code. In your example you'd change `resp = requests.get(...).json()` with `resp = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: requests.get(...).json())`. That is inferior to using a native async library, but gets the job done.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, that sounds like a good generic solution. Though I wonder what makes a native async library superior to a thread wrapper. Is a thread more “heavyweight” or there are other considerations?

Comment: @nalzok treads may affect performance noticeably if you aim at thousands RPS using threads. So for not heavy-load projects threads do nice. I guess, compared to native async lib, thread-safety concern may also be an issue.

Comment: That's a good question. One problem is that with threads the number of tasks you do is parallel is limited by the number of threads in the thread pool (50 or so by default). True async, on the other hand, has no such limit and can easily scale to thousands of concurrent tasks. The other problem is that you lose on the nice properties offered by async, such as cancellation. And you have to deal with threading issues, protect data with mutexes, and so on. All in all, if you use `run_in_executor` for everything, then you should just use `concurrent.futures` directly and not bother with asyncio.

Comment: @user4815162342 That makes sense, but I want to note a downside of "true async": after switching from `ThreadPoolExecutor` to libraries like `aiohttp` &`aioodbc`, my code that stores data from a REST API to an RDBMS actually runs slower. I suppose the IO operations are so cheap that making them asynchronous isn't worth the overhead of context switching & rescheduling? With a thread pool, the synchronous operations can be executed with little disruption in each thread, but now I have millions of `await cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ...")` yielding for each other, which degrades the performance.

Comment: While there are cases where async can be slower, it is usually as fast or faster, so the slowdown might be a consequence of your architecture rather than of async itself. Also, you might be comparing apples to oranges - why would you have "millions of [database operations] yielding for each other" which you didn't have in thread-based code? Async makes it possible (and easy) to limit the number of operations performed at one time, if that's desired, but it's hard to tell without knowing the details of your use case.

Comment: @user4815162342 *why would you have "millions of [database operations] yielding for each other" which you didn't have in thread-based code?* I suppose the control is yielded back to the event on each invocation of `await`, but we don't have such overhead with `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Anyway, [here](https://gist.github.com/nalzok/af3b1b9abe42fc51cc0c13dac72eaff5) is an MCVE of my use case will all details included, should you care to have a look :)

Comment: *I suppose the control is yielded back to the event on each invocation of await* - It is yielded only when the awaitee chooses to suspend, not always. And threaded code also switches between threads (due to the GIL), except it can take/yield control at any point during execution, not just at an `await`.

Comment: Your asyncio code is completely sequential, AFAICT - it contains no calls to `asyncio.gather()`, `asyncio.wait()`, `asyncio.create_task()`, etc. This in contrast to your threaded code where you have calls to `executor.submit()`. So your asyncio problem is not too much parallelism, it's too _little_ (or no) parallelism. Read up on `asyncio.gather()` and related parallelization primitives.

Comment: @user4815162342 Oh I see... Can you point me to some examples of such parallelization primitives? The official documentation is a little abstract and describes each primitive separately, but I cannot see how to fit the pieces together.

Comment: "Read up on `asyncio.gather()` and related parallelization primitives." - `asyncio.gather()` is an example, and this tag contains literally hundreds of examples of its use, as does any [introductory text](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) on asyncio.